# Names of specific SAT variants

Tags: np, satisfiability

I enjoy reading research on satisfiability, but sometimes it's easier to find relevant information when you know the names of the variants.

Example:

- All the clauses are width 3 and must have exactly 1 true literals and 2 false literals: 1-in-3 SAT
- Each clause of width n must have exactly 1 true literal and n-1 false literals: 1-in-k SAT

I'm looking for any of these, if they exist:

- Each clause must have exactly x true literals (x not always equal to 1)
- Each clause can have at most (or at least) x true literals
- Each clause has a number of true literals contained in an interval

Comment: The last three are what is known as *cardinality constraints*.